# Zoom IN issue on map layer with leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, api, leaflet

I have issue with zoom IN on map layer with leaflet.
After a zoom in max, layer map disappear. Whatever value associated with maxZoom, after a zoom in, layer disappear.
Do you know why ?

Below code elements in my code html page:

map = L.tileLayer('https://maps-api.meteoblue.com/v1/tiles/satellite_global/20230608/20230608_1815/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg?apikey=XXXXXXX', {maxZoom: 10, tilesize: 512, attribution: 'Map data © [OpenStreetMap](http://openstreetmap.org) contributors, [CC-BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/)'});